# How to disable infinitely indexing source files in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

My Visual Studio Code (1.16.1) doesn't stop this indexing anymore. I try to wait too long time, but it indexing continues with hard disk extensive loading.

How can i find solution for this problem? I'd like to indexing working, but wan't doing it all of time when Visual Studio runned. Help me, please.

[image]

P.S. When I close Visual Studio Code - hard disk become to still and isn't hearing.

Comment: P.P.S. Indexing was stopped after 5-6 hours. My Ruby files count = 489. But, when i closed VSC and reopen it - indexing was starting again. How i can limit this hard disk loading - i haven't any ideas.

Comment: I have same problem. =/

Answer (score 4):

After two hours of lazy digging to this trouble, i find solution: that is a "vscode-ruby" extension. After uninstalling problem discontinued.

So, question tag need to be updated: 'vscode-ruby' tags needs.

Answer (score 1):

The indexing could be due to a caching process. You can find where this caching is being stored by looking at the path in the list of indexed files.

Then you can add the root path to your `.gitignore` file. In my case, I simply added `.cache/` to my `.gitignore` file.

This resolved the problem for me without having to uninstall the extension.

Answer (score 0):

"Disabling indexing would break most functionality and it would not be helpful providing a config option for this."

https://github.com/bmewburn/vscode-intelephense/issues/71